# Store ID of RowEditing Instead of Index

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

In my application, I give the user the option to search the database. When they click edit, I want the GridView to only show the row they are updating by storing its ID.

I'm trying the following code, but it is not returning anything other than the Control.

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
     string value = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[3].ToString();
}
```

Any ideas on how to store the value that I'm looking for?

Comment: What are you trying to get it? Your question is not clear. In which event are you trying to get the value `RowUpdating`. More code would help to understand the issue.

Comment: The value of cell 3, which is the row ID of the row that edit has been clicked on.

Comment: Is the cell #3 declared as a `BoundField` or a `ItemTemplate`?

Comment: Okay, I updated my code above, and no cell 3 is neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the cell's Text property

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
     string value = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[3].Text;

     // or 
     string value = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[3].Value;
}
```

Or If you have declared the control as `<TemplateField>` for which you are trying to get the value for then try

```
string value = ""
Label lblID = (Label)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("lblID");
value = lblID.Text;
```

Another alternative would be to add `DataKeyNames="ID"` for the gridview which you can retrieve using

```
 // assuming that the value of your datakey is numeric value 
 long Id = long.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Values["ID"].ToString());
```

Note you can add multiple comma separated values to `DataKeyNames` property.