# Gridview loses edit index when value is searched

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview, edit

There is a textbox which searches the value from the Gridview. When the value displays then Every time I click Edit it goes to the first Index Row of the Gridview. I want to only edit the row which has been searched by ID.
For example if I search a value that is in row 8. It displays row 8 which is fine but when I click edit it goes to first row again. Why is this happening?

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString);

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        BindGridView();

    }
}

 protected void BindGridView()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblInventory", con);
    con.Open();
    da.Fill(dt);

    con.Close();

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;

        GridView1.DataBind();

    }

}

 protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblInventory where (Part like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%') or (Brand like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%' )", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();


}

protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string id = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    TextBox Part = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtPart");
    TextBox Description = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtDescription");
    TextBox Qty = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtQty");
    DropDownList Brand = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlBrand");

    TextBox ItemType = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtItemType");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update tblInventory set Part='" + Part.Text + "',Description='" + Description.Text + "',Qty='" + Qty.Text + "',Brand='" + Brand.Text + "',ItemType='" + ItemType.Text + "' where ID=" + id, con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    BindGridView();
}
protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    BindGridView();
}
   protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindGridView();

}
```

Comment: Can you provide little more details on Search ? When you search does the gridview filters and shows rows with value as what you typed in textBox ? any screenshot you have ?

Comment: @R.C - I think it's similar to this: For example if I search a value that is in row 8. It displays row 8 which is fine but when I click edit it goes to first row again. Why is this happening? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25128461/store-id-of-rowediting-instead-of-index

Comment: Right now what I can say is that bind your grid view data using !IsPostback condition in Page_Load. Most of the time this is the reason for losing Edit Index

Comment: I think something is wrong with Button search. Please check details. How would I fix only this part?

Comment: Basically when you search a value and just for example say the searched value, which may be anywhere in any row ( 8, 4, 100...) originally, it is kind of filtered and then this value is showed up in ROW 1 or ROW 2  etc... then it is basically the ROW 1  or 2 which you selected. not the Actual row  = row 8 for example. So try using the EnablePersistedSelection property of gridview. May be this may help. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.enablepersistedselection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @R.C - I enabled it, still doesn't work. It's still losing the index. I thought this could a minor issue and is an easy fix but a week has passed and still I can't do anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your BindGridView Method, it will take care the problem.
Now when you a search a value in any Row and it displays the results, and when edit is clicked, it will stay on the selected Row.

txtSearch is just the ID of your Search TextBox.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    BindGridView(this.txtSearch.Text);


}
}

protected void BindGridView(string column1)
{

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from table1 where (column1 like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%')", con);
con.Open();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column1 ", column1 );
GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
GridView1.DataBind();
con.Close();

}

protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
BindGridView(this.txtSearch.Text);

}

protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
BindGridView(this.txtSearch.Text);

}

protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
BindGridView(this.txtSearch.Text);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks for the help!